# Windows Vista losing drive mappings?

Tags: windows, windows-vista

Everytime I reboot Vista loses it's mappings to the hard drive connected to another machine. IdeaSs? I've set everything to remember the user/password yet always gets lost on a reboot.

Comment: Is this a laptop with a wireless connection? Drive mappings are done to networked connected directories. But the bootup process attempts to map the drives before the wireless network can connect and make those drives connected. With a wired connection, the drives are available earlier in the bootup.

Comment: This is a known limitation in Vista Home...see this...http://forums.techguy.org/networking/1000821-solved-vista-mapped-drives-disappear.html

Comment: It's a wired connection.